# How much Citric Acid to neutralise bicarbonate?

Tags: water

I live in an area with very hard water, where the bicarbonate in the water is 357  mg/L. I would like to add some citric to the tap water to bring it down to around 50mg/L, for the curious, this is for coffee brewing.

How much citric acid would I need to add per liter? If it would be a very tiny quantity, then it would be impossible to weigh it accurately since I have a scale that is only sensitive to ~0.1g. In this case, could I make some solution which I could say add some milileters to a liter of tap water?

Comment: Coffee brewing includes boiling, which should remove the bicarbonates anyway.

Comment: could you clarify? I don't boil it for long periods, just bring the water to a boil.

Comment: That should be enough. After boiling (if even briefly), don't you observe white precipitate in your water, or maybe a deposit on the walls of the vessel?

Comment: Yes that is true. But I don't think all of the carbonate would be neutralized? Also I would like to avoid having to descale the kettle as well